# Constituent or valance quark which has spin $1/2$?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks

I know that the spin of an up-quark is $1/2$ but is this referring to the spin of a valance quark or the spin of a constituent quark (i.e. a valance quark with all the sea quarks and gluon around it)?

Comment: A quark of any kind is defined my intrinsic properties, between them the spin. All the up-quarks, valence or see, will have spin 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a nice illustration](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) of a proton

[image: proton]

you would have to really countup everything at every instant to find the three extra quark called valence quarks. The sea quarks and the valence quarks have different [parton distribution functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1178), but as far as particle characteristics they  are indistinguishable .